# Add custom field for users

Tags: plugins, custom-field, metabox

I am using [Metabox](http://metabox.io) for a while and is a great plugin but I was using in pages and posts. Now I want to add a simple `checkbox` to users profile page, is that possible with Metabox plugin? Can any provide a simple example?

I have tried the following and none works:

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title' => __('Prominent columnist?'),
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'pages' => array('user'),
            'name' => __('Prominent columnist?'),
            'id' => $prefix.'prominent_columnist',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'desc' => 'Sí'
        )
    )
);

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title' => __('Prominent columnist?'),
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'user',
            'name' => __('Prominent columnist?'),
            'id' => $prefix.'prominent_columnist',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'desc' => 'Sí'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Do I sound rude if I say RTFM? If you read the first sentence on wp.org you can see: "...for posts, pages or custom post types..."

Comment: @kraftner I have read the manual and go through the examples on Githhub and apparently you don't so maybe you should take a look to [this](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/blob/master/demo/user.php)

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that. Looks like I had a grumpy morning, excuse me.